# Como inserir o ID no banco visto que é o primeiro campo da tabela?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Eu tenho ID auto increment e estou tendo erro na contagem de colunas com esse código. Como posso inserir o ID junto?

```
    #SQL Execute
    $uir = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO visitados VALUES (:IMO_CODIGO, :CATEGORIA, :BAIRRO, :FOTO_PRINCIPAL, :VLR_VENDA, :AREA_TOTAL, :DORMITORIO, :DATA)");

    $uir->bindParam(':IMO_CODIGO', $imov);
    $uir->bindParam(':CATEGORIA', $cate);
    $uir->bindParam(':BAIRRO', $bair);
    $uir->bindParam(':FOTO_PRINCIPAL', $foto);
    $uir->bindParam(':VLR_VENDA', $vlrv);
    $uir->bindParam(':AREA_TOTAL', $area);
    $uir->bindParam(':DORMITORIO', $dorm);
    $uir->bindParam(':DATA', $adata);

    $uir->execute();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você precisa declarar explicitamente o nome das colunas que estará fazendo INSERT caso queira omitir algum campo, ex:

```
INSERT INTO visitados (nomecoluna, outronomecoluna, maisumnomecoluna ...) VALUES (:IMO_CODIGO, :CATEGORIA, :BAIRRO ...)
```

Comment: Deixa que o banco trate o identificaod e o resto você pode inserir da forma que o amigo propos.

Answer (score 3):

Sem duvidas é melhor declarar os nomes dos campos conforme a [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/34325/13658) do [wryel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/1479/wryel), até mesmo para não precisar obedecer a ordem exata que esta na tabela.

Mas a titulo de informação, também funcionaria desta forma:

```
#SQL Execute
    $uir = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO visitados VALUES (NULL, :IMO_CODIGO, :CATEGORIA, :BAIRRO, :FOTO_PRINCIPAL, :VLR_VENDA, :AREA_TOTAL, :DORMITORIO, :DATA)");
```